# Is there any way to add hibernate.cfg.xml and log4j.properties file from custom folder while running tasks from ant

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, log4j

I am using ANT to run my project, I have my `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `log4j.properties` file under one of my custom folder called `/config`, When I run tasks from ant it fails due to `hibernate.cfg.xml is not found` and shows `log4j appenders warnings`. By any means is it possible to have ant look under your custom folder for these files rather then placing it under `src`.

Target Name -

```
 <target name="controlGRID" depends="compile">
                    <echo>
                Please wait .... GRID is starting up...
                </echo>
                    <java classname="foo.bar.framework.selenium.SetupGrid" classpath="${test.dest}" classpathref="test.c">
                    <arg value="${arg}"/>
                    </java>
                    <echo>
                    GRID Start up complete !
                </echo>
                </target>
```

Classpath -

```
<target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
        <path id="classpath_jars">
            <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
            <!--<pathelement path="${foobar.config}"/>-->
            <pathelement location="${foobar.config}"/>
              <fileset dir="${foobar.config}">
                  <include name="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
                  <include name="log4j.properties"/>
                </fileset>
        </path>
```

Hibernate configuration sequence -

```
hibernateConfig = new Configuration();
        hibernateConfig.configure ();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(hibernateConfig.getProperties());
        hibernateSessionFactory = hibernateConfig.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
```

Comment: Can you show an example ANT task that you're attempting to run?

Comment: Please provide the section of your ant file that you think will help in answering this question.

Comment: @dg99  - I have edited and added the examples in question. thanks

Comment: @bot I have added the section of ant file in question

Answer (score 0):

I have researched my hibernate classes and found a solution:

```
hibernateConfig = new Configuration();
        hibernateConfig.configure (new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/config/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(hibernateConfig.getProperties());
        hibernateSessionFactory = hibernateConfig.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
```

Here earlier my code was -

```
hibernateConfig.configure();
```

and I changed it to -

```
hibernateConfig.configure (new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/config/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
```

Well I found my answer, I hope it'll help somebody else too.